# Karma - Jasmine: Error: No provider for framework:jasmine-ajax

Tags: javascript, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine, karma-jasmine-ajax

I'm trying to get Karma to Jamine's [ajax.js](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/ajax.html)

https://github.com/IDCubed/karma-jasmine-ajax

My karma config has:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    ...
    frameworks: ['jasmine-ajax', 'jasmine'],
  });
};
```

My package.json has:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "bower": "^1.4.1",
    "del": "^1.1.1",
    "gulp": "^3.8.11",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.5.2",
    "gulp-karma": "0.0.4",
    "jasmine-ajax": "^3.1.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.2.0",
    "karma": "0.12.31",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "0.1.7",
    "karma-cli": "0.0.4",
    "karma-jasmine": "0.3.5",
    "karma-jasmine-ajax": "^0.1.12",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "yargs": "^3.7.1"
  }
```

and my spec is like so:

```
  describe("mocking ajax", function() {
    describe("suite wide usage", function() {

      beforeEach(function() {
        jasmine.Ajax.install();
      });

      afterEach(function() {
        jasmine.Ajax.uninstall();
      });

      it('does something', function() {

      });
    });
  });
```

But I have this error:

```
/node_modules/karma/node_modules/di/lib/injector.js:9
      throw error('No provider for "' + name + '"!');
            ^
Error: No provider for "framework:jasmine-ajax"! (Resolving: framework:jasmine-ajax)
```

I'm obviously missing some plugin or something... but what?

Answer (score 1):

Just spent a good 4 hours dealing with the same issue. There are several things going wrong here, the core of it being: there are specific version conflicts and requirements for 'jasmine', 'jasmine-ajax', and 'karma-jasmine-ajax'.

I use Jasmine 1.3, and the current version of `karma-jasmine-ajax` depends on a version of `jasmine-ajax` **that is incompatabile with Jasmine 1.3.x**.

This is noted in the `jasmine-ajax` documentation, but not the `karma-jasmine-ajax` documentation: *"This branch is now version 2.0, if you need jasmine-ajax for Jasmine 1.3.x please grab the last release from that tag."*

In order to fix this specific conflict, I specified **`"karma-jasmine-ajax": "0.1.3",`** in my package.json and removed my dependency on jasmine-ajax (which karma-jasmine-ajax will include itself).

Lastly, the documentation for jasmine-ajax is also incorrect for certain versions of jasmine-ajax: some use `request.RespondWith` and others use `request.response`. My specific version combination required `request.response`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Karma 3.0.0, and it returns this error if the frameworks are not configured as plugins like the following. I've created a [pull request](https://github.com/IDCubed/karma-jasmine-ajax/pull/25) to update the documentation.

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    frameworks: ['jasmine-ajax', 'jasmine'],
    plugins: ['karma-jasmine', 'karma-jasmine-ajax']
  });
};
```